# Uso de superglobais dentro de uma sessão

Tags: php, variáveis-globais

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    include './db_unifacex.php';
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['contador']=0;
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.1;URL=http://localhost/geraCode/content.php">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        <link type="text/css" href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
</html>
```

**content.php**

```
    <?php 
    include './db_unifacex.php';
    session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        <link type="text/css" href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body style="background-image: url(imgs/bk.jpg);">
        <div class="header">
            <img class="logo" src="imgs/cife_logo.png">
            <div class="titulo">
                Gerador de Newslatter
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h2> <?php echo $_SESSION['contador']+1;?>º Notícia </h2>
                    <form class="formulario" action="validar.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Titulo:</label> <input required type="text" name="titulo" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Mensagem:</label> <textarea required name="mensagem" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Foto:</label><input required type="text" name="foto" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="enviar" type="submit" name="enviar" class="form-control btn-default" value="Próximo">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <form action="fim.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="enviar" type="submit" name="fim" class="form-control btn-default btn-disable finalizar"  <?php if($_SESSION<4){echo 'disabled';}?> value="Finalizar">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 ">
                    <h2>Pré-visualização: <?php echo $_SESSION['contador']+1;?>º Notícia</h2>
                    <div class="panel panel-defaul">
                        <div class='panel-body'>
                            <?php
                                $row = row($_SESSION['contador']);
                                echo $row;
                                $linha = ultimos();
                                var_dump($linha);
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <hr>
            <div class="rodape">
                Produzido por Rafael Pessoa
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php fim();?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**validar.php**

```
    <?php
include ('./db_unifacex.php');
session_start();
//Variáveis recebidas do index.php
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
    $foto = $_POST['foto'];

//Variáveis do banco de dados
    $host = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=boletim";
    $passwd = "senha";
    $username = "user";
//Conexão com o banco
    try {
        $conn = new PDO($host, $username, $passwd);
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
    }
//Inserção dos dados
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO noticia(titulo, mensagem, enderecoUri) VALUES(:tit, :mens, :end)");
    $stmt->bindParam(":tit", $titulo);
    $stmt->bindParam(":mens", $mensagem);
    $stmt->bindParam(":end", $foto);
    $stmt->execute();  
//Soma da sessão
    $_SESSION['contador']++;
    ?><a href="index.php"><button>Voltar</button></a>
```

Eu estou precisando saber se tem como modificar o valor de uma variável `superglobal`. Tenho que passar uma variável de uma página para outra e depois voltar para a página antiga somado +1.

Em outras palavras, preciso de um contador `superglobal`. Estava tentando fazer isso com a `superglobal $_SESSION`, mas percebi que não funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem sim como fazer com `$_SESSION` . Mas como voce não inseriu o código, vou fazer um exemplo:
**pagina1.php**

```
// inicias as sessoes
session_start();
//verifica se a sessao contador nao existe
if(!isset($_SESSION['contador'])){
//se ela nao existir, inicio ela com o valor padrao 0
$_SESSION['contador']=0;
}
else{
// mas se ela existir, apenas somo +1
$_SESSION['contador']++;
}
```

Ai na **página2.php** Seria o mesmo código:

```
 // inicias as sessoes
session_start();
//verifica se a sessao contador nao existe
if(!isset($_SESSION['contador'])){
//se ela nao existir, inicio ela com o valor padrao 0
$_SESSION['contador']=0;
}
else{
// mas se ela existir, apenas somo +1
$_SESSION['contador']++;
}
```

Ou o mesmo código de uma forma bem resumida usando o operador ternario:

```
// inicias as sessoes
session_start();
!isset($_SESSION['contador'])?$_SESSION['contador']=0:$_SESSION['contador']++;
```

> Para quem não conhece, esse operador possui essa sintaxe
>
> (condição)**?** aqui a condição é verdadeira **:** aqui ela é falsa;

O possível erro que você esta tendo provavelmente é que não esta dando `session_start()` em todas as paginas.
Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Cara, é bem por aí, mas o valor da variável $_SESSION['contador'] vai se manter a mesma em todas? Por exemplo, eu defino ela no começo do template index.php. No index eu tenho um <form> e envio para a página validar.php. Nessa nova página eu quero recuperar o valor de $_SESSION['contador'] e somar mais 1. Isso que eu não estava conseguindo.

Comment: @RafaelPessoa sim, sempre se manterá. Mas lembre-se de dar `session_start();` em todas as paginas que utilizará a sessao

Comment: Ela vai sempre se manter, e se quiser alterar ela vai se alterar, e alterará em todas as paginas tambem. E se a resposta lhe ajudou marque como resposta :)

Comment: @RafaelPessoa um exemplo de aplicação seria em um carrinho de compras, que se utiliza em varias paginas, ou ate mesmo em login, onde armazene os dados do usuario logado, caso ainda nao tenha usado

Comment: Pois bem, eu não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Dou start no index e atribuo 0 à variável, redireciono para outra página. Nessa outra página eu envio um <form> para uma terceira página de validação. Quando valido, incremento a variável $_SESSION['contador']++. Depois que clico no botão que retorna a página anterior a variável não se alterou.

Comment: @RafaelPessoa faz um teste colocando exatamente como eu coloquei, dando um echo nessa sessao em cada pagina, e ve se esta funcionando

Comment: Essa outra pagina, possui o start?

Comment: acabei de atualizar o post com o código. Estou fazendo dessa forma, como podes observar. A intenção é que quando vá para validar a variável seja incrementada. Mas quando volta para a página anterior ele não permanece 0.

Comment: Verificando sempre se essa sessão existe, para ai sim incrementar. Retire o echo onde nao precise mostrar o valor

Comment: @RafaelPessoa , Lembrando que `echo $_SESSION['contador']+1;` não incrementa mais 1 na variavel

Comment: eu sei. Eu só quero antecipar a informação. Mas mesmo da forma que você falou continua a não incrementar.

Comment: Resolvi. O problema que estava acontecendo era que você tinha trocado a ordem no operador ternário. Ele deveria incrementar caso a resposta fosse positiva. 
Além disso, havia outro problema. Como meu index está com redirecionamento automático, e o meu botão de retorno estava programado para encaminhar para o index, toda vez que voltava de validar.php ele resetava a sessão.

Comment: @RafaelPessoa consertei, havia mesmo trocado ali, editei colocando o sinal de negação que tinha esquecido. :)